# How to install python correctly on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, directory, installation

How can i install python correctly?
When i install it manually it is in the 
    `/usr/local/bin` 
directory but that causes many problems, for example i am not able to install modules.
I want to install it into 
    `/usr/bin`

Comment: What modules you unable to install? May be you should try [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distro.  Most of distros have it in its repository and for installing you just need to use your package manager.  for example on ubuntu it's: `sudo apt-get install python` or on fedora it's: `su -c 'dnf install python'`

Comment: When I try `sudo apt-get install python` i cant run it because it still trys to launch `/usr/local/bin/python` how can i change that?